# Opening tool panel in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ag-grid

The doc says there should be a gridOptions.showToolPanel(show) function, but in the actual object there is only a Boolean property. You can set this property true, but this has no effect on the grid.

What's the proper way to show/hide the tool panel from code?

Answer (score 0):

Searched through code:

gridApi.showToolPanel(true);

Edit: or gridOptions.api.showToolPanel(true);
..if you identify [gridOptions] in your ag-grid tag.

Comment: api.showToolPanel has been deprecated since v19; use gridOptions.api.setSideBarVisible(true);